# Correlation Matrix in an Event History Analysis - 11 years - 25 Variables

Tags: correlation, survival, panel-data

I'm currently writing my thesis, and I received feedback from my professor that i need to show the correlations between all variables during the time span of my research.

N: 291 
Years: 11 (2000 - 2010)
Total variables: 25

I have created a correlation matrix in SPSS (using R for the analysis), I have done this for all 11 years and similair results show. Therefore I presented only one in my thesis (year 2005). This however was not enough according to the professor.

Is their a way to show the correlations between variables during the years and simultaneously show the changes per year.
My data looks like:

---

ID - Start - End - Time | Var1| Var2| Etc |

Every subject has a line per year that it does not experience the event. On event, that subject is removed.